# Automatic properties with null value

Tags: c#

I have following Problem.

My Auto Properties SearchedObjClass,SearchedProp ,SearchedPropValue result into null value although i assigned values in main program to them:
Can some one help me to find out what the Problem is:

```
class ADClassNew
{
    public static DirectoryEntry createDirectoryEntry()
    {
            string ldapusername = "Username";
            string ldapuserpass = "Password";

        using (DirectoryEntry root =new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            ADClassNew adclass = new ADClassNew();
            root.Path = adclass.LdapPath;
            root.Username = ldapusername;
            root.Password = ldapuserpass;
            root.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            return root;
        }


     }

    public string SearchedObjClass { get; set; }
    public string SearchedProp { get; set; }
    public string SearchedPropValue { get; set; }
    public string LdapPath { get; set; }
    public StringCollection LoadProperties { get; set; }

    public SearchResult searchDirectory()
    {

        DirectoryEntry searchEntry = ADClassNew.createDirectoryEntry();
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
        search.SearchRoot = searchEntry;
        ADClassNew adclassnew = new ADClassNew();

       //string _searchedObjClass = SearchedObjClass;
       //string _searchedProp = SearchedProp;
       //string _searchedPropValue = SearchedPropValue;

       search.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})({1}={2}))", adclassnew.SearchedObjClass, adclassnew.SearchedProp, adclassnew.SearchedPropValue);
       //search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=administrator))";
       search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");
           SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
       return result;

    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ADClassNew adclassnew = new ADClassNew();
        adclassnew.LdapPath = "LDAP://MyDomain";
        adclassnew.SearchedObjClass = "User";
        adclassnew.SearchedProp = "Displayname";
        adclassnew.SearchedPropValue = "administrator";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking that it is null?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *do* anything with the object that's created in the form constructor - it just goes out of scope and will be collected.  Are you expecting the values to persist across **ALL** instances of `ADClassNew`?  If so then use `static` properties:

```
public static string SearchedObjClass { get; set; }
public static string SearchedProp { get; set; }
public static string SearchedPropValue { get; set; }
public static string LdapPath { get; set; }
```

then set them in your initialization using theclass name instead of an instance:

```
ADClassNew.LdapPath = "LDAP://MyDomain";
ADClassNew.SearchedObjClass = "User";
ADClassNew.SearchedProp = "Displayname";
ADClassNew.SearchedPropValue = "administrator";
```

Alternatively you can make the object a property of the form to re-use it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ADClassNew _adClassNew {get; set;}

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _adclassnew = new ADClassNew();
        _adclassnew.LdapPath = "LDAP://MyDomain";
        _adclassnew.SearchedObjClass = "User";
        _adclassnew.SearchedProp = "Displayname";
        _adclassnew.SearchedPropValue = "administrator";
    }
}
```